# Download a file from remote server location

Tags: java, download, network-programming

Hi I have to download a file from our svn server location. 
file url is like this-
https://abc.xyz.com/svn/MyProject/trunk/documents/abc.docx  to download.
 Please Help on how to download it.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple : open a connection and copy the inputStream to the destination file outputStream :

```
public void downloadFile(String location, File destinationFile) throws IOException
{
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( destinationFile )){
        URL url = new URL(location);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        IOUtils.copy( connection.getInputStream(),  fos);
    } 
}
```